# Iterating over several GUI elements

Tags: powershell, for-loop, foreach, repeat

I have a GUI based form with a series of fields on it and want to update the corresponding label when text is entered into one field.  I've been able to get it to work using the following code

```
$objTextBoxRD1.add_keyup({$objLabelLU1.Text = Get-Date})
$objTextBoxRD2.add_keyup({$objLabelLU2.Text = Get-Date})
$objTextBoxRD3.add_keyup({$objLabelLU3.Text = Get-Date})
$objTextBoxRD4.add_keyup({$objLabelLU4.Text = Get-Date})
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same result?

I tried the following but when I enter text into any `$objTextBoxRD` fields it only updates `$objLabelU4`.

```
$Count = 1
foreach ($User in $ISDept) {
    $objTextBoxRD = Get-Variable -Name ('objTextBoxRD' + ([string]$Count)) | Select -Expand Value
    $objLabelLU = Get-Variable -Name ('objLabelLU' + ([string]$Count)) | Select -Expand Value

    $objTextBoxRD.add_keyup({$objLabelLU.Text = Get-Date})
    $Count++
}
```

The `$objTextBoxRD` and `$objLabelLU` variables have been generated from arrays and would like to automate this section as the number of variables that get created can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect your textbox elements in an array instead of using individual variables, so you can iterate over them with a `for` loop. Since you want to use corresponding variables in a scriptblock you probably need to generate that scriptblock, though. Try this:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $objTextBoxRD.Count; $i++) {
    $sb = [scriptblock]::Create("`$objLabelLU$($i+1).Text = Get-Date")
    $objTextBoxRD[$i].Add_Keyup($sb)
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, relevant fields are now updating as expected and don't have to worry about editing the code as users get added/removed from the group.